# Два одновременных провайдера поиска для яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

У меня есть карта в которой я сделал поиск по своим объектам. А как сделать так, что бы при отсутствии попадания в мои результаты, поиск производился уже не по моим объектам, а по улицам, например "yandex#search". Понимаю что нужно как то добавить второго провайдера поиска, помимо своего, но как это реализовать, никаких примеров не нашел. Поиск по своим объектам реализовал по аналогии с примером https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search

Попробовал, но что то не вышло, то ли неправильно функцию добавлял, то ли не туда и у меня то вообще поиск не работал, то даже карта не погружалась. Вот рабочий вариант (с 1 провайдером):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Многоугольник</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=3261ce08-c60a-4114-96f8-ce820abf124a" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  
   ymaps.ready(init);
            
            function init() {
                // Создаем список (массив) подсказок
                var podskazki = [
                     
                        "ТОС «Виктория»",                     
                        "ТОС «Максимум Света»",                     
                                              
                    ];
                // выполняем поиск по подсказкам
                var find = function (podskazki, find) {
                    return podskazki.filter(function (value) {
                        return (value + "").toLowerCase().indexOf(find.toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    });
                };
                // создаем провайдер поиска 
                var myProvider = {
                    suggest: function (request, options) {
                        var res = find(podskazki, request),
                            arrayResult = [5],
                            results = Math.min(options.results, res.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < results; i++) {
                            arrayResult.push({displayName: res[i], value: res[i]})
                        }
                        return ymaps.vow.resolve(arrayResult);
                    }
                }
                // Создание подсказок в поиске
                var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('poisk', {
                    
                    provider: myProvider,
                    noSuggestPanel: false,
                    boundedBy: [[48.61, 134.98], [48.31, 135.29]],
                    strictBounds: true, 
                    results: 19  
                     
                });
                
                // поиск по выбору подсказки                 
                suggestView.events.add('select', function () {  
                    Search()
                    })
                    
                // поиск по Enter
                $("#poisk").keyup(function(event){ 
                    if(event.keyCode == 13){
                        Search()
                    }
                });
                // поиск по нажатию "лупы"
                $('.custom-search').click(() => {
                    if ($('#poisk').val() != undefined) {
                        Search()
                    }
                });

                // Непосредственно поиск в панели
                function Search () { 
                    var request = $('#poisk').val();
                    searchControl.search(request);
                }   

                // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с заданным id ("map")
                var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center: [48.48, 135.08],
                    zoom: 14,
                    controls: ['zoomControl', 'typeSelector',  'fullscreenControl', 'searchControl'] // "Элементы управления (Зум, слои, фулскрин, поиск)
                    
                },             
                { // Ограничение области карты Хабаровск + загород 
                    restrictMapArea: [[48.61, 134.98], [48.31, 135.29]],
                    // Ограничение зума
                    minZoom: 10,
                    maxZoom: 17
                }) ,   
                
                // Создание полигонов и добавление их на карту.
                myObjects = ymaps.geoQuery({
                    type: "FeatureCollection",
                    features: [
                        
                         
                    
                        {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Polygon',
                                coordinates: [[ [ 48.4872099152, 135.044750889 ], [ 48.4865858624, 135.045233687 ], [ 48.4863005786, 135.044150075 ], [ 48.4869567290, 135.043726286 ], [ 48.4872099152, 135.044750889 ] ]]
                                
                            },
                            options: {
                                fillColor: '00bfbf', // Цвет заливки
                                fillOpacity: 0.45, // Прозрачность заливки
                                strokeColor: 'ff007f', // Цвет обводки
                                strokeWidth: 2, // Толщина обводки
                                strokeOpacity: 0.5, // Прозрачность обводки
                                fildColor: "Кировский", // Кластер объекта 
                                filtColor: "2020" // Год объекта
                                
                            },
                            // Содержимое балуна
                            properties: {                        
                                balloonContentHeader: '<a href="https://khv27.ru/projects/territorialnoe-obshchestvennoe-samoupravlenie/reestr-tos/index.php?ELEMENT_ID=106497">ТОС «Виктория»</a>', // Заголовок 
                                balloonContent: '<b>Председатель: </b>' + 'Савинов Е.А.<br/>' + '<b>Адрес: </b>' + 'ул. Казачья гора, дом 9-7<br/>' + '<b>Район: </b>' + 'Кировский<br/>'  + '<b>Дата создания: </b>' + '10 февраля 2020<br/>' + '<b>Реализованные проекты: </b>' + 'НОВЫЙ ДВОР 2021<br/>', // Содержимое
                                balloonContentFooter: 'Телефон: </b>' + '409144', // Футер 
                                hintContent: "ТОС «Виктория»" // Подсказка объекта
                            }
                        },                        

                        
                         
                    
                        {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Polygon',
                                coordinates: [[ [ 48.5213356048, 135.106362622 ], [ 48.5206620838, 135.107070725 ], [ 48.5214817114, 135.108052414 ], [ 48.5216670166, 135.107526701 ], [ 48.5215850548, 135.106754225 ], [ 48.5214638935, 135.106566470 ], [ 48.5213356048, 135.106362622 ]]]
                                
                            },
                            options: {
                                fillColor: '00bf00', // Цвет заливки
                                fillOpacity: 0.45, // Прозрачность заливки
                                strokeColor: 'ff007f', // Цвет обводки
                                strokeWidth: 2, // Толщина обводки
                                strokeOpacity: 0.5, // Прозрачность обводки
                                fildColor: "Железнодорожный", // Кластер объекта 
                                filtColor: "2020" // Год объекта
                                
                            },
                            // Содержимое балуна
                            properties: {                        
                                balloonContentHeader: '<a href="https://khv27.ru/projects/territorialnoe-obshchestvennoe-samoupravlenie/reestr-tos/index.php?ELEMENT_ID=106500">ТОС «Максимум Света»</a>', // Заголовок 
                                balloonContent: '<b>Председатель: </b>' + 'Сергеев М.С.<br/>' + '<b>Адрес: </b>' + 'пер. Краснодарский, дом 19а<br/>' + '<b>Район: </b>' + 'Железнодорожный<br/>'  + '<b>Дата создания: </b>' + '11 февраля 2020<br/>' + '<b>Реализованные проекты: </b>' + 'Спортивная площадка<br/>', // Содержимое
                                balloonContentFooter: 'Телефон: </b>' + '+7 (4212) 40-91-42', // Футер 
                                hintContent: "ТОС «Максимум Света»" // Подсказка объекта
                            }
                        },                         
                    ]
                    

                }).addToMap(myMap); 

                // Создаем коллекцию для поиска по названию объектов
                myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(),

                // Создаем массив с данными.
                myPoints = [
                                             
                        { coords: [48.4872099152, 135.044750889], text: 'ТОС «Виктория»' }, 
                                             
                        { coords: [48.5213356048, 135.106362622], text: 'ТОС «Максимум Света»' }, 
                                             
                          
                                    ];
        
                // создание поисковой строки
                searchControl = myMap.controls.get('searchControl');

                // настройка поисковой строки Яндекса
                searchControl.options.set( 
                    {
                        provider: new CustomSearchProvider(myPoints),
                        noPlacemark: true, 
                        placeholderContent: 'Введите адввврес ТОСа',
                        boundedBy: [[48.61, 134.98], [48.31, 135.29]],
                        strictBounds: true,  
                        results: 10, //  требуемое количество результатов 
                        resultsPerPage: 5,                         
                        position: {
                            left: -400 //  смещение строки поиска
                        }
                    }
                );

                    
                // Проверим попадание результата поиска в один из ТОСов.
                searchControl.events.add('resultshow', function (e) {
                    highlightResult(searchControl.getResultsArray()[e.get('index')]);
                });

                // Сохраняем координаты переданного объекта и находим полигон.
                function highlightResult(obj) {
                    // Сохраняем координаты переданного объекта.
                    var coords = obj.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                    // Находим полигон, в который входят переданные координаты.
                        polygon = myObjects.searchContaining(coords).get(0);

                    if (polygon) {
                        polygon.options.set('fillOpacity', 0.2);
                        polygon.balloon.open();
                    } 
                }  

                // Провайдер данных осуществляет поиск геообъектов по массиву points.                        
                function CustomSearchProvider(points) {
                    this.points = points;
                }                

                // Провайдер ищет по полю text стандартным методом String.ptototype.indexOf.
                CustomSearchProvider.prototype.geocode = function (request, options) {
                    var deferred = new ymaps.vow.defer(),
                        geoObjects = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(),
                        // Сколько результатов нужно пропустить.
                        offset = options.skip || 0,
                        // Количество возвращаемых результатов.
                        limit = options.results || 20;
                        
                        var points = [];
                        // Ищем в свойстве text каждого элемента массива.
                        for (var i = 0, l = this.points.length; i < l; i++) {
                            var point = this.points[i];
                            if (point.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                                points.push(point);
                            }
                        }
                        // При формировании ответа можно учитывать offset и limit.
                        points = points.splice(offset, limit);
                        // Добавляем точки в результирующую коллекцию.
                        for (var i = 0, l = points.length; i < l; i++) {
                                var point = points[i],
                                    coords = point.coords,
                                    text = point.text;

                                    geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
                                        name: text + '',
                                        description: text + 'description',                                                
                                        boundedBy: [coords, coords]
                                    }));
                        }

                        deferred.resolve({
                            // Геообъекты поисковой выдачи.
                            geoObjects: geoObjects,
                            // Метаинформация ответа.
                            metaData: {
                                geocoder: {
                                    // Строка обработанного запроса.
                                    request: request,
                                    // Количество найденных результатов.
                                    found: geoObjects.getLength(),
                                    // Количество возвращенных результатов.
                                    results: limit,
                                    // Начинает поиск сразу после нажатия Энтер
                                    skip: offset
                                }
                            }
                        });

                // Возвращаем объект-обещание.
                return deferred.promise();

                searchControl.events.add('load', function (event) { // Проверяем, что это событие не "дозагрузки" результатов и по запросу найден хотя бы один результат.
                    
                    if (!event.get('skip') && searchControl.getResultsCount()) {
                        searchControl.showResult(0);
                    }
                }); 
                            
            }                      
} 



  </script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="search">
          <input type="text" id="poisk" placeholder="Введите название ТОСа" autocomplete="off" style="margin-right: 0px;">
          <div class="custom-search">
          </div>
        </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Я так и не понял в итоге куда именно нужно прописать условие на количество найденных результатов

Comment: Вариант менять провайдера, если результатов поиска - 0, не пробовали? Сама смена довольно простая, можно и обратную смену выполнять, после запроса: mySearchControl.options.set('provider','yandex#search'); Если не выйдет - кидайте рабочий пример кода - посмотрим.

Comment: Идея хорошая, благодарю за содействие, но у меня так и не вышло это реализовать, хоть это и очень просто)).  К сообщению добавил код

Comment: Ковырялся короче почти два дня и в итоге максимум чего удалось добиться, это одновременное открытие подсказок от двух разных провайдеров.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось осуществить одновременный поиск по двум разным провайдерам, примар куска кода :

```
            searchControl.events.add('optionschange', function (event) { 
                
                if (!event.get('count') == 0) {
                    earchControl.options.set('provider', 'yandex#search');
                } else {
                    earchControl.options.set('provider', 'new CustomSearchProvider(myPoints)');
                }
            });
```

Но вот теперь как то нужно сделать так что бы еще поисковые подсказки вылазили по двум провайдерам

Comment: Какие то странности с этим кодом, то ли кэш не отчистил то ли еще чего, вообщем поработал он не так долго и перестал.